# Kendo window resizestart() not working?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'm using Kendo window (the version date is by Q3 2013). Does someone knows how to simulate the window *resizestart()* and *resizestop()* events ? I need to execute some instructions during these events.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `resize` event

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
<script>
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  resize: function() {
    // user has finished resizing the window
  }
});
</script>
```

For more info check the kendo docs http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#events-resize